# Mensagem sobre dppx e dpi no console do Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Quando entro no sistema interno que estou fazendo aqui na empresa vou no console e aparece uma mensagem estranha:

> Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)

O que significa?

**obs:** é só no meu sistema, em outros sites como Google por exemplo não aparece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dppx é uma métrica de detecção de resolução/tamanho de tela, assim como o dpi. No entanto o dpi não representa a tela de uma maneira exata.

- dppx: Número de pixels do dispositivo/tela por pixel de CSS
- dpi: Pontos por polegada

O chrome por padrão exibe essa mensagem caso a página utilize dpi em seu css, uma vez que o dppx é uma métrica mais exata e orientada ao dispositivo que está visualizando. Mas é apenas um aviso do navegador recomendando o uso do dppx ao invés do dpi para que suporte melhor os diversos tipos de tamanhos de tela.

Desabilitar a mensagem creio que não seja possível, pois é um comportamento padrão do navegador. Mas é possível converter o uso do dpi para o dppx.

```
1px / 1dppx = 96dpi
```

No seu caso *2dppx* poderiam ser usados no lugar dos *144dpi*.

Mas, acredito que esse recurso ainda não seja bem suportado por navegadores como IE.

Seguem links para ajuda:

- http://drewwells.net/blog/2013/working-with-dppx/
- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#resolution

Comment: Você sabe se é possível desligar essas mensagens?

Comment: Creio que não. Mas é possível converter dpi para dppx e eliminar a mensagem. Editei a resposta com mais informações.

Comment: Meu laptop tem resolução de tela de 120 dpi. Nesta situação devo então supor que 1dppx = 120 dpi ?